# Roulette probability - something doesn't add up

Tags: probability, gambling

I know I must be missing something very rudimentary but I can't find it.

**Background:**

On a roulette there are:

- 18 black values
- 18 red values
- 2 values

Therefore,

**Betting on either red or black** yields a winning probability of **18/38** (obvious advantage to the house).

The odds on this kind of bet are 1:1 (You win a matching sum to what you bet, or you lose your bet).

Another type of bet, is **betting on a specific number**. This yields a winning probability of **1/38** (even more obvious advantage to the house). The odds on this kind of bet are 35:1 (if you win you get your dollar plus 35 if you lose, the dollar is gone.).

So far so good.

**My question:**

If I bet **$1 on 9 black numbers** (35:1 odds) my chance of wining is **9/38** (9 outcomes will be a win). I will At the worst case I will lose all my bets; best case, I will lose 8 dollars, and win 35 (if one of my numbers won). So I have a 9/38 chance of being profitable.

Now if in addition to betting on 9 black numbers, I also **bet $10 on red to win**, to me it seems like I would have a 18/38 chance of having my color win and an additional 9/38 chance of having my number win (of opposite color).

**Therefore**, I have a 27/38 (or just over 70%) chance to win (come out profitable) every turn?

That is,

- I have a 30% chance of losing 19 dollars
- 23% chance of having one of my numbers win: if I win a number I lose 18 dollars and get an additional 35 dollars
- 47% chance of having my color win: If I win the color, I lose 9 dollars and win an additional 10 dollars

Could this be? Surely not! What am I missing?

Comment: Here's another way. Pick 35 numbers and bet $1$ on each number. If one of your numbers wins, you make a $1$ profit. So you have a 35/38 chance of making a profit!

Comment: You have a 70% chance of winning somthing.  And a 30% chance of losing something.  The 30% of the something you lose is more than the 70% of the something you win so the house is happy because even the win more often than you lose, when you *do* lose you lose a lot more.

Comment: Imagine a slot machine that if you put in a \$1 you have an 80% chance of winning back \$1.10.    If 2,000 people play it in a day, *on average* 1,600 people will win 10 cents (and the house loses \$160) and 400 people lose a dollar (and the house gains \$400).  So on the whole the house makes \$240$ *despite* the fact that 80% of the players are winners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us compute the expectation of you reward $R$:

$$\mathbb E(R)=\dfrac{11}{38}(-19)+\dfrac{9}{38}(35-18)+\dfrac{18}{38}(10-9)=\dfrac{-11 \cdot 19+9\cdot 17+18}{38}=-1$$

On average you will lose 1$ per game... Even if you have the sentiment to win in 70% of the cases. This is very pernicious! Actually when you lose, you lose quite a lot.

Comment: Could you please explain your calculation to me? The fractions I get, but the numbers in brackets confuse me.

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich the numbers in brackets are exactly the ones you gave in your bullet points: -19: losing 19 dollars, 10-9: lose 9 and win 10... I reordered then to match the order of your bullet points though

Comment: Ok, the maths totally makes sense to me, but I can't get this intuitively. I mean, I logically explained how I arrived at 70% chance of winning. Now while you proved me wrong, I would appreciate if you could explain where was the flaw in my logic. In any case, I will mark you as the write answer.

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich surely you have 70% of chance of winning. But in this 70% you count 48% of only winning 1\$ (not much). But you also have 30% of chance of losing 19\$ (this is a lot). Then **on average** you will lose 1\$. But if you play only once there is 70% of chance that you will go back with some money, it is true. The risk is that in 30% of the cases you will lose 19\$...

Comment: Or is it that I do have a 70% chance of winning, but I win very little in proportion to what I stand to lose that winning 3 games, and losing 1 still results in my losing more money than making. Is that it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to duplicate your answer, I just came to the same conclusion my self. Thank you!

Comment: yes that is the idea! Look at this other example. You have a die. You roll it, if you get 1 you have to pay 10\$. Otherwise you win 1\$. You have 83% of chance to win 1\$, great! But you can still lose 10\$ And if you **keep playing** you will start losing money

Comment: And as far as the house cares  They don't care if 83% of the customers win $\$1$ if 17% are losing $\$10$.  So they don't care if you make one $$\19$ dolllar bet with a 70% chance of winning.  So long as *other* people are making similar bets.  Even if *you* play only once and assume you will win and do win, the house will play the *expected* averages.  And they *will* win.

Comment: I might be wrong but i think the third outcome is in fact -9, or 10-10-9 to be precise since betting on color means you just get back what you bet